# How can the difference between the "grammaticality" and "grammar" tags be described?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I know the difference between [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), and [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality), but I was wondering how the difference between those tags can be described.

Can anybody suggest a sentence that can be used to describe the difference, and which could be used in the tag wiki of one of the tags?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's any objective distinction. But for the purposes of ELL I think all it comes down to is that **questions tagged [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) ask if some particular construction is grammatical or not.**

They're just a particular subset of all questions concerned with [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), so it doesn't really matter whether they're explicitly tagged with that as well (if not, it's implicit anyway). By the same logic, there's no reason for the *grammar* tag description to be worded so it excludes questions about *grammaticality*.

Comment: Actually, there is a difference between [tag:grammar], and [tag:grammaticality]. I was just wondering if the difference could not be made clearer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I don't see that as a very helpful comment. If you think *you* know of some "objective" difference, why don't you actually describe what you have in mind? This isn't a guessing game.

Comment: @snailplane: Again, I don't see that as a very helpful comment. I can't see any difference between your first sentence and my answer, and I have no idea why you preface your second sentence (which appears to say exactly the same thing for the *third* time) with the word "unfortunately". There is no objective standard by which anyone could endorse or dispute whatever you guys are trying to say - we are *here and now* defining what ***we*** want these terms to mean in our specific ELL context. Just post your definitions up and let them be voted on, so we can all see the lie of the land.

Comment: I deleted my comment because you felt it was unhelpful.  As I said, I have no particular suggestions for the tag wiki, so I can't post them up to be voted on.  I did vote your answer up, since I agree with most of it.

Comment: @snailplane: I apologise for the snarky tone of my comment. I think kiamlaluno has raised an important question (which is why I upvoted the question). I provided one possible answer, because I think it *is* worth separating out *is this sentence grammatical?* questions from others that fall under the general "grammar" tag (which is arguably too broad to be worth using at all anyway). But I would really like to see either some more wholehearted endorsement, or clear alternatives, to my suggested distinction.

Comment: Well, what you described _is_ an objective difference. If I am asking if a sentence/phrase is grammatically acceptable, I am asking a kind of question; if I am asking the meaning of a grammar term (e.g. _indirect object_), I am asking a different type of question. The question here is the following: Is there anything else that needs to be added in the tag wiki of one of those tags?